# Ubuntu doesn't fit screen after installation

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, display-resolution, intel

I'm completely new to ubuntu and linux. I've looked everywhere but nothing seems to be working.

The problem is ubuntu is not fitting screen and has square shape like it doesn't recognize intel onboard graphics:

[image]

I always have this problem after Windows installation but I could easily solve that by downloading intel driver manually. How can in do something like that in ubuntu?

In the display setting I only have three resolution options which are far less than my monitor resolution.

I apologize for my English and Thank you in advance.

**update: I solved the problem by adding custom resolution** but I dont think its the best solution possible.

Comment: Hello. Is there a physical button or some method on the monitor itself you can use to have the monitor reset itself?

Comment: What is the native resolution for your display? Is this an internal or external monitor?

Comment: Monitor has a button for auto resolution but doesn't solve the problem. @David

Comment: native resolution is 1366x768 and its an external monitor.@matigo

Comment: Did you try to change resolution in settings? You can also change driver (bottom left icon with 9 dots and then search additional driver) normally graphics driver is set to xorg by default but you can change it.

Comment: @GuillaumeF93 I changed resolution several times. I only have 3 options: 1024x768, 848x480, 800x600 and its set to 1024x768. Additional drivers says "no additional drivers available."

Comment: @Afshin you can display your intel onboard graphics ' name in a terminal by typing : 
> lspci -nnk | egrep -iA3 "VGA"

> sudo lshw -c video  . And then search for a ubuntu driver package that manage your graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue was caused due to that I had enabled the option "Adjust for TV", once disabled it picked up again full screen space.

Comment: I've never heard of this option. I searched for it and apparently its only available for AMD cards.

Comment: Makes sense since I'm using an amd, didn't knew that option was due to graphic card manufacturer. Thanks!